# download all RPMs from a metapackage

Tags: rpm, source

example of what im trying to do

```
    # yumdownloader net-snmp.x86_64 --source
Enabling epel-source repository
epel-source                                                                                                                                                             | 2.9 kB     00:00     
No source RPM found for 1:net-snmp-5.3.2.2-17.el5_8.1.x86_64
No source RPM found for 1:net-snmp-5.3.2.2-17.el5.x86_64
Nothing to download
```

How do you download all the RPM's inside a metapackage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like your trying to download the source RPMs but they don't exist:

`No source RPM found`

Why not try to use something like

```
yum install net-snmp -y --downloadonly --downloaddir=/opt
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `yumdownloader` but you say you want to download all the RPMs and your example is for net-snmp.  I know for sure that `reposync` will do what you are looking for.

If this still fails, it's likely your repository isn't configured correctly.

`reposync --repoid=epel-source --source`

[man reposync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/reposync)